# VB code for Excel- value of a variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am an amateur programmer and trying to accomplish the following task.

I have a set of instructions coded into an Excel workbook that is launched by the user via the Add-Ins menu. This particular routine aims to merge up to 20 different user-selected files, meaning the source folder file paths can be unique for each file and vary user to user.

I have a straight assignment of the file name and file path to each of the 20 string variables (i.e. Dim refFile1, refFile2, refFile3, ... refFile20) once the routine is called. After the code cycles through the 20 variables to identify which are assigned a file:

```
If refFile1 <> 'select file' then
   FileCount = FileCount + 1
End If
```

This now establishes that total times needed for my For Loop to run the actual merging code.

QUESTION: 
How do I get the original string value assigned to "refFile1" and so on when embedding the reference to the variable name through another variable?

I have a For Loop to start the process:

```
For CurFile = 1 to FileCount
```

and then try to recycle the 'CurFile' variable to reference the root file path/name to open the specific workbook:

```
CurRefFile = "refFile" & CurFile 'use variable to loop through 20 possible variables with base variable name "refFile" + # 
Set curWB = Workbooks(curRefFile)
curWB.Open
```

in the above code, Excel tries to open the Workbook explicitly named "refFile1", the recent value of variable curRefFile.

How do I get the 'mapped' value of curRefFile == refFile1 == [user's file path/name] to rise up into the Workbooks() function for the correct workbook name?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest you use an array rather than 20 file path variables then you can loop through that on both occasions.

Comment: I tried to construct an answer that might get you started but your understanding of VBA seems so confused that I did not know where to start. For example, VBA does not allow you to construct a variable name at run time. To achieve this effect, use an array of file names. Perhaps an Add-in is the long-term solution but first learn VBA and then design and implement your code. (1) How does the use tell your code what files to merge? (2) What file are they to be merged into? Etc, etc.

Comment: Thanks Tony...
My code module is a couple hundred lines of code, I only provided the relevant portion of how I'm trying to make a variable relate to a second variable already created.  To your points, the user launches the macro and has a GUI where they are provided with merge options -- save formatting, data starts on line, and 20 available "select file/open file" buttons which store the file name and path in a text box. The code creates a new fresh page, writes to one tab that stores statistics (number of file), and goes through the Save As routine in the user-supplied source folder.

Comment: Regarding Arrays: I'm good with the theory, however was never successful at loading and calling the array data.  Researching array types, I have not found a dynamic-length string viable via an array, but possibly through the newer collections and lists methods.

Comment: If you include @TonyDallimore in any reply, I will be told there is a message for me.  Otherwise I have to remember to check every question I have responded to.

Answer (score 0):

I am still not sure what you are doing but I suspect the code below demonstrates actions you will need.

I created a workbook with one module and one user form.  The code within the module is:

```
Option Explicit

' Declare a global variable so it can be accessed from the user form.
' The empty parentheses declare this as a uninitialised, dynamic array.
' Declaring FileName as dynamic means I can define its size at run time.
Public FileName() As String
Sub Control()

  Dim InxF As Long

  Load UserForm1
  UserForm1.Show

  ' There is no elegant method of determining if an array is unitialised.
  ' The code below needs to know if there user has exited the form without
  ' selecting any files. I think the easiest solution is for the form
  ' to declare the array with one, empty entry if no files have been
  ' specified.

  If LBound(FileName) = UBound(FileName) And _
     FileName(LBound(FileName)) = "" Then
    ' User did not select any files.
    Debug.Print "User closed form without selecting any files"
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' Using LBound (lower bound) and UBound (upper bound) means this
  ' routine does not care how big array FileName is.
  For InxF = LBound(FileName) To UBound(FileName)
    Debug.Print FileName(InxF)
  Next

End Sub
```

This module loads the user form and then `Shows` it to pass control to it.  Once a user form has been closed and control returned to the module, any data within the form is lost.  So the user form must save any data required in global variables before exiting.  The statement `Public FileName() As String` near the top declares this global variable.

On return, from the user form, the module check for no files being selected and then outputs file names of any files selected to the Immediate Window.  The Immediate Window should be displayed at the bottom on the right when you open the VB Editor.  Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> if it is missing.

The user form is displayed as:

[image: Display appearance of user form]

Down the left I have five text boxes names txtFile1 to txtFile5.  I have a list box named lstFile and two buttons names cmdText and cmdList.  The code behind this user form is:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub cmdList_Click()

  ' This routine loads the contents of the list box to global array FileName

  Dim InxItem As Long

  ' Size array FileName according to how many entries are in the list box
  ReDim FileName(0 To lstFile.ListCount)

  For InxItem = 0 To lstFile.ListCount - 1
    FileName(InxItem) = lstFile.List(InxItem)
  Next

  Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub cmdText_Click()

  Dim InxC As Long
  Dim InxF As Long
  Dim NumFiles As Long

  ' Count number of file text boxes with values
  NumFiles = 0
  For InxC = 0 To Controls.Count - 1
    If Left(Controls(InxC).Name, 7) = "txtFile" Then
      If Controls(InxC).Text <> "" Then
        NumFiles = NumFiles + 1
      End If
    End If
  Next

  ' Size array FileName according to how many file text boxes contain values
  ReDim FileName(0 To NumFiles - 1)

  ' Copy text box values to array
  InxF = 0

  For InxC = 0 To Controls.Count - 1
    If Left(Controls(InxC).Name, 7) = "txtFile" Then
      If Controls(InxC).Text <> "" Then
        FileName(InxF) = Controls(InxC).Text
        InxF = InxF + 1
      End If
    End If
  Next

  Unload Me

End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  ' This is called when user form is initialised.  This routine is used
  ' to prepare the user form for the user.

  ' I have used it to fill the text boxes and the list box with values.

  txtFile1.Text = "File 1"
  txtFile3.Text = "File 3"
  txtFile5.Text = "File 5"

  lstFile.AddItem ("File 1")
  lstFile.AddItem ("File 3")
  lstFile.AddItem ("File 5")

  ' Allow for the user closing the form without selecting any files
  ReDim FileName(1 To 1)
  FileName(1) = ""

End Sub
```

As I understand it, you have text boxes to hold file names which the user initialises by clicking buttons.  I am not interested in creating equivalent code so I have used the form's initialise routine to create some possible values.  I often use a list box to hold values like yours so I have shown how to add rows to a list box.  You would have `txtFile??.Text = "?????"` and `lstFile.AddItem ("?????")` within appropriate routines ready to be selected by the user.

The click routine for the command button cmdText saves the contents of the text boxes in the global array FileName.  I said that you cannot construct VBA variable names at runtime.  This is not true for form controls.  My code looks through all the controls for those with a name starting `txtFile`.  The code saves any values it finds.

The click routine for the command button cmdList saves the contents of the list box in the global array FileName.

I hope that is all clear.  Come back with questions if necessary but the more you can understand on your own, the faster you will develop your understanding of VBA and user forms.